# Unable to create snowflake reader account - trial account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using trial account, initially I created a reader account and deleted it. After that I am unable to create another reader account and getting the following error. I am not able to contact the support as well. Any help is appreciated.

> Number of managed accounts allowed exceeded the limit. Please contact Snowflake support.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, "you need to submit a case to Snowflake support". Could you tell me why you can not connect to the support?

Go to snowflake community:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/

Register and login, and then click "submit a case". Select "I am a 30-day trial user", and validate yourself. Then you should be able to submit a case.