# Resource Utilization for External Table Refresh

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What compute is utilized to refresh an external table. 
When executing
 `alter external table x refresh 'custom_location'` I am not seeing any activity in warehouse tab.
But, the statement ran into timeout after running for 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

The external tables refresh execution is a metadata management feature that uses [the cloud services layer](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#cloud-services) of Snowflake to perform its work. It does not use a virtual warehouse from your account ([although, some charges are incurred](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#billing-for-refreshing-external-table-metadata)).

Your question includes an issue but lacks information on [how many files](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-external-table.html#parameters) were added before a manual refresh was performed, their format, if [partition columns](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#partitioned-external-tables) are in use, etc.

The refresh work can take longer dependent on various factors. If it is a repeating issue and the incremental automatic refresh feature is not an option for you, consider [logging a support case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557449/13472370) to have them investigate.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. The external location (aws s3) has more than 3M files. The external location is multi-key partitioned, and has lots of tiny files. That caused Snowflake thresholds to kick in and fail initial ingestion. Snowflake suggested to use lazy initialization and it worked. In addition to cloud services layer credits consumed, I see compute credits as well. Isn't that supposed to be?.